# React maximum update depth exceeded | useEffect dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a certain piece of code that I want to run when any of the dependencies change. One of those dependencies is not being used inside the effect

```
  const { contractParams, serviceInstance } = entityStore;
  useEffect(() => {
        const [first, second, third, fourth] = getParamDetails(contractParams);
        setFirst(first);
        setSecond(second);
        setThird(third);
        setFourth(fourth);
    }, [contractParams, serviceInstance]);
```

I want to run this code or trigger a re-render when any of them changes. However, i understand since I am not referring  `serviceInstance` inside this useEffect, its not exactly a dependency per se. However, when I run it, I get this error

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

If I remove serviceInstance, it goes away.Both of the dependencies are array. Is it treating serviceInstance a diff value on every update? What am I missing? Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: How are you getting `entityStore`?

Comment: @AlexanderNied - Its injected via Provider.

Comment: I don't see where `serviceInstance` is a dependency, it's not referenced in the `useEffect` callback.

Comment: @DrewReese - you are right. I mentioned in the description as well. But on its change, I want this code to re-run. Basically re-render, because store is already updated and things are in place. Also, if I mention dependency and its not being used, this error doesn't make sense

Comment: I would look at how it is getting defined-- if it is a different object reference each time, the `useEffect` dependency array will understand it to be changed and re-run.

Comment: Is there any relation b/w `serviceInstance`  and all the functions inside useEffect:


        setFirst(first);
        setSecond(second);
        setThird(third);
        setFourth(fourth);

Comment: Please share where `entityStore` is declared and what its value is. You mention both `contractParams` and `serviceInstance` are arrays, how are they computed? If setting any of these state somehow triggers either of these arrays to be recomputed and thus a new array reference then this can trigger the render looping.

Comment: Also check if `serviceInstance` is an empty array . Put console.log to check it

Answer (score 1):

There are several points to be covered here:

#### Array and object equality testing

Arrays & Objects will often (re-)trigger a `useEffect` even if they have not changed. The reason for this is that Javascript is not capable of assessing equality on such structures. Consider these two:

```js
["a", "b"] === ["a", "b"] // <-- false
{a: "a", b: "b"} === {a: "a", b: "b"} // <-- also false
```

If the nesting in your `serviceInstance` is relatively shallow, you could manually decide which values should in fact trigger a refresh.

You mention `serviceInstance` is an array, so perhaps something like:

```js
const [prop1, _, prop3] = serviceInstance;

useEffect(() => { 
  // code
}, [prop1, prop3])
```

Another solution is to use a deep compare useEffect variant, something like:
https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect

Please note though, as [Dan Abramov himself states](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1104414469629898754?lang=en), there's a reason why `useEffect` doesn't work that way. Depending on how your data is structured, this can really create a bottleneck in the performance of your app.

#### Side effects

As Alia pointed out in the comments, if one of the setters in your effect actually ends up changing the contents of `serviceInstance` it will create a loop.

You should consider separating concerns:

When the `contractParams` change, one `useEffect` will set the params. You can then use a second `useEffect` that only looks at `serviceInstance` (or as seen above, parts of it) to then trigger a refresh.

```
  import uuid from "uuid";

  const [componentKey, setComponentKey] = useState(uuid())
  const { contractParams, serviceInstance } = entityStore;
  const [first, second, third, fourth] = getParamDetails(contractParams);
  useEffect(() => {
        setFirst(first);
        setSecond(second);
        setThird(third);
        setFourth(fourth);
    }, [first, second, third, fourth]);

  const [prop1, _, prop3] = serviceInstance;
  useEffect(() => {
     // refresh code
    setComponentKey(uuid());

  },[prop1, prop3]);

  return <YourComponent key={componentKey}/>
```

using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid to manage your uuid

Please note the above code is purely theoretical, as I do not know how you intend to use these values. If `serviceInstance` is being used in the render part of your component, then it should trigger a refresh on its own. You may need to rethink the structure of said component.

#### Edit: Dependencies on hooks

As a side note, depending on the strictly your react linter is set to enforce (eg: react-hooks/exhaustive-deps), using variables that are not used within the hook will throw a warning. This is usually a good sign that something is structurally wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I've gathered so far you want to trigger an `useEffect` hook by some additional dependency, that is an array, and that by including it triggers render looping.

I'm assuming that *something* in the effect callback is causing this array to be updated and returned back to the component as a new array reference.

To skirt this array reference equality check you can stringify the array and instead uses this as the additional triggering dependency. *Only when the array **serializes** to a **new string** will it trigger the effect*.

[Exchange between Kent Dodds and Dan Abramov regarding the "fast-deep-equal"](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1104414469629898754?lang=en)

Dan suggests if the deep equality is shallow enough to just use `JSON.stringify(obj)`.

Example:

```js
const a = ["a", "b"];
const b = ["a", "b"];

console.log(a === b); // false, different array reference
console.log(JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)); // true, serialized equality
```

Code:

Note, as @ltroller points out, that if you've the React-hooks linter installed as part of your project that it should complain about the extraneous dependencies. If this is the case you *can* disable the linter rule for that line, but use caution as this will disable all the dependency checks should the hook logic ever be updated and your dependencies *do actually* change.

```
const { contractParams, serviceInstance } = entityStore;

useEffect(() => {
  const [first, second, third, fourth] = getParamDetails(contractParams);
  setFirst(first);
  setSecond(second);
  setThird(third);
  setFourth(fourth);
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [contractParams, JSON.stringify(serviceInstance)]);
```

Naturally, if you need more customized equality like wanting `["a", "b"]` and `["b", "a"]` to be considered equal, then you can write a custom serializer to, for example, sort *then* stringify the result for equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useRef hook to solve this problem which stores the previous reference of the variable. So that you run the code only when the value is changed instead of running whenever the value changes.

```
             const { contractParams, serviceInstance } = entityStore;
              const serviceRef = useRef(serviceInstance);
              useEffect(() => {
                    if(JSON.stringify(serviceInstance) !== JSON.stringify(serviceRef.current.value){
                    const [first, second, third, fourth] = getParamDetails(contractParams);
                    setFirst(first);
                    setSecond(second);
                    setThird(third);
                    setFourth(fourth);
            }
                }, [contractParams, serviceInstance]);
```